# Accelerated Mobile Pages not able to display a form

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I've been converting a site to Accelerated Mobile Pages and now I'm trying to implement a contact form. I've got amp-forms running on the page and I've placed the example code of an HTML AMP contact form from the [AMP by Example site](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/), but the form is not displaying and the page validates without any AMP errors. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to your sample page.

Comment: You may want to try the [suggested workaround in this forum](https://forums.cubecoders.com/chat/issue-with-amp-page-not-loading-or-showing-login-boxes). It stated that there's a known issue where AMPs CPU usage climbs and the web interface becomes unresponsive. Also make sure that you have imported the corresponding library for `amp-form`: `<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>`

Comment: Like  I stated above, "I've got amp-forms running on the page" or <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script‌> is on the page.

Comment: @AlanP can you please provide the exact code with what you are trying?